# Create athena table with column as unstructured JSON from S3

Tags: amazon-athena

I am currently creating an Athena table as follows:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `foo_streaming`(
  `type` string, 
  `message` struct<a:string,b:string,c:string>)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `dt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://foo/data'
```

However, instead of treating the **message** struct as structured data, I would like to read it as a JSON blob, because the data could change at any point.  How do I do this with Athena?

I tried the following, but it gives me an error. I tried googling, but found nothing.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `foo_streaming`(
      `type` string, 
      `message` JSON)
    PARTITIONED BY ( 
      `dt` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://foo/data'
```

Sample data from S3 would like like:

```
{ "type": "GTF", "message": { "a": 1, "b": 2 } }
{ "type": "GTB", "message": { "c": 1, "d": 2, "x": { "testid": "abc" } } }
{ "type": "GTE", "message": { "error_code": 1 } }
```

Comment: Can you post some sample JSON varying records?

Comment: Hi @Prabhakar, it would look like the following:

`{ "type": "GTF", "message": { "a": 1, "b": 2 } }
{ "type": "GTB", "message": { "c": 1, "d": 2, "x": { "testid": "abc" } } }
{ "type": "GTE", "message": { "error_code": 1 } }`

Comment: ^^ The message part could be different each time.

Comment: I tried verifying if this is valid JSON on jsonlint.com and found that it is an invalid JSON format.

Comment: The only way around this issue I found that worked was to re-write the JSON coming into S3, so that each "type" generated it's own unique name.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `string` as type, and then [Athena/Presto's JSON functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) to extract values from the blobs.

You can see this solution in action in [the documentation for how to query CloudTrail logs with Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudtrail-logs.html). The `requestparameters`, and `responseelements` properties are JSON, but are service-dependent, and therefore can't be described with a struct.

`json` doesn't work as a type because it's not a type recognised by Hive, it's a Presto thing, IIRC. I find it pretty confusing in general when types are supported or not, or called different things depending on whether it's DDL or DML (e.g. `string` and `varchar`).