# Exploding a json column in Athena using Presto stored procedure

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

**The Scenario**

I've chose S3 folder location to create the table from a csv file, which has 1 column in JSON format. This needs to be exploded in way that creates many entries for one particular user & event.

**The Problem**

1. Athena Table looks something as follows:

```
agenda_data, event_id, partner_id, record_last_updated, user_id
"{'enclosed_data': {'task_active': 'true', 'status': 'completed'}, 'Agenda-1': {'currentProgress': '', 'timelines': '30/4/2020'}, 'Agenda-2': {'currentProgress': ' ', 'timelines': '25/4/2020'}, 'Agenda-3': {'currentProgress': ' ', 'timelines': '25/4/2020'}, 'Agenda-4': {'currentProgress': ' ', 'timelines': '28/4/2020'}, 'meta': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'Summary': {'finYear': '2020'}}, 'event_id': '20200407181839', 'record_last_updated': '2020-04-07T18:24:44.557362Z','user_id': '121000'}",20200407181839,Actionable,2020-04-06T13:20:31.114397Z,121000
"{'enclosed_data': {'consolidator': {'task_active': 'true', 'status': 'completed'},'Agenda-1': {'currentProgress': '', 'timelines': '25/4/2020'},'Agenda-2': {'currentProgress': 'On Going', 'timelines': '20/4/2020'},'Agenda-3': {'currentProgress': 'Completed', 'timelines': '07/4/2020'},'Agenda-4': {'currentProgress': ' ', 'timelines': '13/4/2020'},'meta': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'Summary': {'finYear': '2020'}}, event_id': '20200407202551',record_last_updated': '2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z', user_id': '12354'}",20200407202551,Actionable,2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z,12354
```

2. The Column `agenda_data` contains JSON data, which needs to be exploded. To put it clearly I'll repost the minimized structure of JSON.

```
{
  "enclosed_data": {
      "task_active": "true",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    "Agenda-1": {
      "currentProgress": "",
      "timelines": "25/4/2020"
    },
    "Agenda-2": {
      "currentProgress": "On Going",
      "timelines": "20/4/2020"
    },
    "meta": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "Summary": {
      "finYear": "2020"
    }
  },
  "event_id": "20200407202551",
  "record_last_updated": "2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z",
  "user_id": "121000"
}
```

3. I need to project the Data of Agendas only when exploded, for same I tried resolving multiple blogs, I found Documents sensible though, here they go:
   [link1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html): Which helps very little
   [link2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/flattening-arrays.html): Doesn't apply since I don't have Arrays in here
   [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299638/create-athena-table-with-column-as-unstructured-json-from-s3): Couldn't get either

**The Expected output**

The expected output is as follows:

```
event_id, partner_id, record_last_updated, user_id, agenda, currentProgress, timelines
20200407181839, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 121000, Agenda-1, " ", "30/4/2020"
20200407181839, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 121000, Agenda-2, " ", "25/4/2020"
20200407181839, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 121000, Agenda-3, " ", "25/4/2020"
20200407181839, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 121000, Agenda-4, " ", "28/4/2020"
20200407202551, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 12354, Agenda-1, " ", "25/4/2020"
20200407202551, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 12354, Agenda-2, "On Going", "20/4/2020"
20200407202551, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 12354, Agenda-3, "Completed", "07/4/2020"
20200407202551, Actionable, 2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z, 12354, Agenda-4, " ", "13/4/2020"
```

**EDIT #1**

Success so far, that I could manage to parse json using presto function as follows:

**QUERY**

```
with meeting_data AS 
    (SELECT '{
  "enclosed_data": {
      "task_active": "true",
      "status": "completed"
    },
    "Agenda-1": {
      "currentProgress": "",
      "timelines": "25/4/2020"
    },
    "Agenda-2": {
      "currentProgress": "On Going",
      "timelines": "20/4/2020"
    },
    "meta": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "Summary": {
      "finYear": "2020"
    }
  },
  "event_id": "20200407202551",
  "record_last_updated": "2020-04-07T20:32:48.215545Z",
  "user_id": "121000"
}' AS blob)
SELECT json_extract(blob,
         '$["Agenda-1"]') AS agenda1, json_extract(blob, '$.enclosed_data.status') AS m_status, json_extract(blob, '$.Summary.finYear') AS finYear
FROM meeting_data
```

**OUTPUT**

```
agenda1, m_status, finYear
{"Agenda-1": {"currentProgress": "", "timelines":"25/4/2020"}},"completed", "2020-21"
```

OPEN QUESTIONS

1. I understood I can access the JSON when put it manually, I need this to be fetched from column one by one using loop, but how?
2. Once looped, how do I explode and get the expected output by repeating the other column values which aren't in JSON format?
3. Can this be achieved by writing a function/stored procedure in presto?

Comment: Did you try the regex functions such as: SELECT regexp_extract_all('1a 2b 14m', '\d+'); -- [1, 2, 14]? You can use a few of the array options, even if you don't have arrays in your JSON data.

Comment: Try to convert your JSON to JSON Array  `CAST(JSON 'yourColumnName' AS ARRAY(JSON))`

Comment: @Guy , zealous I do not have array in json, can it still work? Either ways I'll give this a try and keep you guys posted.

Comment: You don't need to have arrays in JSON. Use regex ('Agenda-\d', for example) to find all the agenda items in the data, and then you can parse the array from the regexp_extract_all query into your needed format.